# Status of Dirac Video, Speex audio, FLAC as tracks inside OGG container

Tags: video, audio

Can someone update me with statuses of using Dirac Video, Speex Audio and FLAC inside OGG format? Are there support of desktop or mobile browsers?
Also how is OGG(OGV)? Does it well supported and has future?

I am asking because of HTML5. 
These codecs were mentioned in specs : http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-source-element.html#the-source-element

```
Speex audio alone in Ogg container
<source src='audio.spx' type='audio/ogg; codecs=speex'>
FLAC audio alone in Ogg container
<source src='audio.oga' type='audio/ogg; codecs=flac'>
Dirac video and Vorbis audio in Ogg container
<source src='video.ogv' type='video/ogg; codecs="dirac, vorbis"'>
```

I wonder is it dead ones or soon will get mature?

Answer (score 1):

Ogg is certainly alive and well, Speex and FLAC are in heavy use the world over,

Dirac (which apparently was used to broadcast HD video from the Beijing Olympics) has split into two forms, with the BBC keeping Dirac as a research implementation, and  a higher quality version, Shrodinger, in development)

Ogg Vorbis is supported on many products: (list from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorbis))

- Openmoko Neo 1973 and Neo Freerunner
- Devices based on Google's Android platform support Ogg Vorbis media files.
- Digital audio players such as Cowon's D2 and iAudio X5 ship with Ogg Vorbis support.
- Samsung YP series of digital audio players ships with Ogg Vorbis support.
- The majority of iriver devices provide Ogg Vorbis support up to Q10 bitrates.
- Cowon C2 (Ogg and FLAC support)
- various Sandisk devices
- Meizu's M6 and M3 Digital Audio Players
- Elta 8844 MPEG4 DVD/DivX player can play music files in both MP3 or Ogg Vorbis format
- Vedia A10 plays Ogg Vorbis and FLAC in addition to MP3, AAC and other formats
- S1 MP3 Players Ogg Vorbis also supported since at least 2006, though this is not typically listed on the player's packaging.
- GamePark Holding's Linux based portable gaming consoles (GP32, GP2X F100-F200, GP2X Wiz) officially support Ogg Vorbis.
- Pioneer XW-NAV1K
- RIM BlackBerry 9800 "Torch" and 9670 "Style"
- VDO Dayton CD1737X car radio supports 8-192kbit/s Ogg Vorbis files
- HP TouchPad was given support for Ogg Vorbis with the webOS 3.0.4 update

To summarise, those formats are definitely not dead, however Dirac is possibly less useful for you. Many devices can handle the formats, and Ogg Vorbis is very popular.

Comment: Thanks for replay I also find that Speex is very useful:The Google Mobile App for iPhone currently incorporates Speex.[15] It has also been suggested that the new Google voice search iPhone app is using Speex to transmit voice to Google servers for interpretation.[16]
Speex is used as the voice compression algorithm in the Siri voice assistance on the iPhone 4S.[21] Since text-to-speech occurs on Apple's servers, the Speex codec is used to minimize network bandwidth.